# Filter grouped products with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a class **productInfo**, which has properties **ProductId** and **Locale**, and tried to show the products with the current locale(id), and also show the products with the same id.

That means, after grouping by product id, once there is one product's locale is equal to current locale, we will show this group( with their individual locale).

The following is the seudo code/example:

```
 public class productInfo
{
 public int ProductId {get;set;}
 public int LocaleId  {get;set;}
}


List<productInfo> listProduct = List<productInfo>();
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 1 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 2 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 3 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 200, LocaleId = 4 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 300, LocaleId = 1 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 300, LocaleId = 5 });
listProduct.Add(new productInfo{ ProductId = 400, LocaleId = 6 });
```

if the current locale is equal to 1, then the final list should contain:

```
productInfo { ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 1 }
productInfo { ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 2 }
productInfo { ProductId = 100, LocaleId = 3 }
productInfo { ProductId = 300, LocaleId = 1 }
productInfo { ProductId = 300, LocaleId = 5 }
```

and the following ones will be removed from the list:

```
productInfo { ProductId = 200, LocaleId = 4 }
productInfo { ProductId = 400, LocaleId = 6 }
```

How to achieve this by using Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
productList.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
           .Where(g => g.Any(p => p.LocaleId == 1))
           .SelectMany(g => g)
           .ToList();
```

Replace 1 with the current locale.